# How to pause video when opening a popup

Tags: javascript, html, function, video, popup

I have a carousel with multiple video's on different slides. Some of these slides have a popup text. When you click the button, you get a textbox with text. I want the video to stop playing when the popup is clicked and opens, and continue playing when the popup closes again.

I'm very new at Javascript and that's probably why I haven't been able to successfully google how to do this. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-item">

<video controls autoplay class="myvid" id="player2">
<source src="assets/vid/s2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction();"> Title
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1"> <h3> Title </h3> <p> Popup content </p> </span>
</div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

I know I have to use video.pause() but I haven't been able to figure out where and how exactly I can use that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1

```
function myFunction() {
let popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
let player2 = document.getElementById('player2');
popup.classList.toggle("show");
popup.className == 'popuptext show' ? player2.pause() :  player2.play();
}
```

Method 2 (Not really too different)

```
  function myFunction() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  let player2 = document.getElementById('player2');
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  player2.paused ? player2.play() : player2.pause();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  let video = document.getElementById("player2");
  video.pause();
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xdah30k8/)

Answer (score 2):

When you click open the popup pause the video. And same when you close the player use `vid.play()`

```
function myFunction() {
  let vid = document.getElementById("player2"); 
  vid.pause();
  let popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I'm not sure how to do vid.play() now, if I repeat the code with play it doesn't work. How can I specifically target when the popup opens and when it closes?